# I can not remove disk from Storage Space

Tags: windows-10, raid, storage, storage-spaces, storage-pool

I have a storage pool that shows low capacity but there are actually at least 2.55TB free.

[image: Show enough space]

The storage pool is a simple drive so there is no redundancy. I am trying to remove one drive but I am not able because it thinks there is not enough room.

[image]

Comment: Does a Storage Pool do any pre-allocation?  Or does it add redundancy/checksum information anywhere?